# Why VS stops debugging and detaches iis express automatically

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, iis-express

I am using Visual Studio premium 2013 and developing website using ASP.Net MVC. I am using iis express to run my site and test, debug during development. My problem is VS automatically stops and detaches from iis express automatically soon after i start running my site from VS -> Start. Because of this I can't debug many of my features. I can still run my site because I have disabled 'Enable Edit and continue' but can't debug code.

I want to know why visual studio automatically stops. This was working fine for weeks but got this issue all of a sudden and I am sure I have not done any settings change.

Thanks in advance